# How to make an ISO?

Tags: linux, iso

I made an ISO out of a directory using the command

`mkisofs filename.iso source_directory`.

When I mount the ISO though, I see the file names are pruned. Actually the file names will be something like `ABCD_ASKDKDK.rpm`, but in the ISO it will shorten to some fixed characters.

How do I check what standard is my source ISO (I have an ISO at a remote location) and a directory similar to that locally. I am trying to create a similar ISO.

Comment: @Chris S - his first question was less than a month ago, and he's a new user.. if in another 2 months he had no accepted answers, I *might* be concerned - but accepting answers is distinctly not required (though it's nice!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the joliet extension and you should get the real filenames.

```
mkisofs -J -o cd_image.iso /directory
```

From wikipedia:

> > Joliet is the name of an extension to the ISO 9660 file system. It has been specified and endorsed by Microsoft and has been supported by all versions of its Windows OS since Windows 95 and Windows NT[citation needed]. Its primary focus is the **relaxation of the filename restrictions** inherent with full ISO 9660 compliance.

Comment: That was nice pointer , but it didnt solve problem completely as I got Joliet tree sort error . So i used the option 
mkisofs -joliet-long option . I hope this really solves the problem , some of the rpm names are really big ! There is an option called joliet-longer , wondering if I shud use that for being on the safe side ? !
Is there a way to get all the info about a ISO  ?
I want to cross check the source ISO . How do I find the details ?
Like we have Gspot program in windows to get all codec details .

Answer (score 3):

If you don't pass `-J` or `-R`/`-r` then you've produced a bare ISO 9660 filesystem, which has 31 character filename maximum, 8 part maximum tree depth, and everything in capitals.